# java : html request return error 400 on android 2.x and not 4.x

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get an xml file from a distant server.
The server asks a username and password.

My code works fine on Android 4.x but on Android 2.x i get an Error 400.

> 400 Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

here is my code :

```
URL url = new URL("http://username:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:80/pathToXML/file.xml");
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
String val = (new StringBuffer("username").append(":").append("password")).toString();
byte[] base = val.getBytes();
String authorizationString = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(base, Base64.DEFAULT));
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorizationString);
uc.connect();

InputStream ins = uc.getInputStream(); // it fails on this line
```

I tried many things (adding Content-Length, SetRequestMethod to POST, set user-Agent) but it doesn't work.

If someone has any idea i'm open to it.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Cheers